# Avoid potential senario where token has not loaded before button click in NUXT app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am following [zendesks docs](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/widget-messaging/web/authentication/) to get my jwt token.

query returns the api endpoint for the jwt and at token i get everything I need.

Is what I am doing below the best way to avoid the situation where the user has already clicked the chat button but the token has not loaded. I know with ajax I would do the following:

```
jwtFn: function (callback) {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'goes/here',
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (json) {
                callback(json.token);
              }
            });
```

but what is the correct way to get this done for vue3. Would a fetch or an await be better and if so how would I correctly write this?

```
const query = useGetZendeskSupportQuery()
const token = ref();

const { scriptTag, load, unload } = useScriptTag(
  `https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=${config.public.zendeskApiKey}`,
  () => {

      zE('messenger', 'loginUser', function (callback: any) {
        const zendeskToken = query.data?.token;
        token.value = zendeskToken;
        callback(zendeskToken);
      })

....
```